# How do I get an Instance of a class instead of its subclass?

Tags: grails

I have 2 domains:

Incident:

```
class Incident {
    String title
    String description
}

static mapping = {
    tablePerHierarchy(false)
}
```

And IncidentWithTimers which extends Incident:

```
class IncidentWithTimers extends Incident {
    int currentResponseTime
    Date responseTimeEndDate
}
```

IncidentWithTimers is not an actual table in the database, it's a database view.

Now when I try to get an Incident instance from a controller, it somehow returns an IncidentWithTimers instance:

```
def index() {
    Incident curIncident = Incident.get(params.incident)
    println(curIncident.getClass())// "class IncidentWithTimers"
}
```

Since this domain is a view, I disabled all modifications by throwing exceptions in the `beforeInsert`/`Update`/`Delete`, in the IncidentWithTimers class.

When I try to modify and save the curIncident, it tries to access the `beforeUpdate()`, and throws the error, while I never wanted to change the `IncidentWithTimers` in the first place.

What can I do about this?

Comment: Does the Incident ID in `params.incident` refer to an instance of `Incident` or `IncidentWithTimers`?

Comment: Neither. params.incident gets the value of the incident from the querystring. (So url.com/?incident=1 would return 1).

Comment: What I mean is, following your example, is the Incident with ID 1 an `Incident` or `IncidentWithTimers`? Also, are the IDs returned by the view that `IncidentWithTimers` is mapped to coming from the same table the `Incident` is mapped to? Yes, I'm implying that both should share the same ID "namespace".

Comment: did you disable the version field version false

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa The IncidentWithTimers is a database view that combines Incidents with some other calculated fields. Therefore every Incident is a IncidentWithTimers.

Comment: So does that mean that the `IncidentWithTimers` view contains all of the columns from the `incident` table plus the calculated columns `current_response_time` and `response_time_end_date`? If so, why not use derived properties instead? https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#derivedProperties

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa More or less. The view has a refference to the Incident table, and those additional fields. I calculate the timer using a join and a group by so I can add all time spans over multiple days (1 day = 1 row). Therefor a derived property is not really an option.

Comment: Ok. Let's do an experiment. `Incident.list()*.class.unique()`. That will list the classes of the incidents. You should see `Incident` and `IncidentWithTimers`.

Comment: Never mind i know what's wrong.

Comment: Please mark as answered if the solution helped you. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the view includes every `Incident`, not a subset of them as would happen with a subclass. As you said, every `IncidentWithTimers` is an `Incident`.

The solution is to either use a query instead of a subclass, or make `IncidentWithTimers` an independent  duplicate class rather than a subclass.

I think the former is the best option because the intent is clear.