# Left joining unrelated entities with Grails / Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, grails, join, hql

I am accessing a shared DB with Grails that was created and is populated by the ORM of another application and want to perform a LEFT JOIN coupled with aggregate functions on it without modifying the underlying table structure. This should ideally happen on a high level base, e.g. with HQL, Criteria or some similar way.

These tables are *unrelated*, they don't have a relationship defined by foreign keys. The tables use a system of String identifiers that can be used to execute a join.

For that reason the only way I could find to join these unrelated tables in Grails until now was with a native SQL query. Left joins in HQL require    a relationship defined in the table (e.g. `left join checkoutJournal.checkoutDate` which would require a `checkoutJournal` field in `RentalCar`, which to my understanding would add extra columns to the DB table)

My domain classes look like this - the only thing they do at the moment is represent the table structure of the DB.

```
   class RentalCar {
     String identifier
     static mapping = {
       table 'rental_car'
     }
     ...
   }

   class CheckoutJournal {
     String identifier
     String renterName
     Date checkoutDate
     static mapping = {
       table 'checkout_journal'
     }
     ...
   } 

   class RepairJournal {
     String identifier
     String repairDescription
     Date repairDate
     static mapping = {
       table 'repair_journal'
     }
     ...
   }
```

The resulting data set I want to build should have this structure (in JSON Notation):

```
[
    {
       identifier: "xyz",
       // = max checkout date from CheckoutJournal, identifier String NOT unique
       lastCheckoutDate: "2015-10-31 20:06:17.738831",
       // all repairDate entries from RepairJournal that match identifier,
       // realized with aggregate function in SQL
       repairHistory: [
          "2015-10-31 20:06:17.738831",
          "2015-10-30 20:06:17.738831",
          "2015-10-29 20:06:17.738831"
       ] 
   }, {
     // Another rental car with the same structure
      ...
}]
```

My native SQL query for the desired result would look something like this:

```
SELECT
  rc.identifier,
  coj.renterName,
  array_agg(rej.repairDate)

FROM rental_car rc

LEFT JOIN checkout_journal AS coj
  ON coj.identifier = rc.identifier 
  AND coj.checkout_date =
    ( SELECT max(checkout_date)
      FROM checkout_journal c
      WHERE rc.identifier = c.identifier )

LEFT JOIN repair_journal AS rej
  ON rc.identifier = rej.identifier 

GROUP BY rc.identifier, coj.renter_name
```

- What is the best way to realize my query without altering the DB
  scheme?

I was thinking about subclassing RentalCar (to separate the composed entity from the basic entity) with the additional relationship to CheckoutJournal and RepairJournal adding something similar to

```
  static mapping = {
            checkoutJournal indexColumn: [name: "identifier", type: String],
                              joinTable: [column: "identifier"],
            repairJournal indexColumn: [name: "identifier", type: String], 
                              joinTable: [column: "identifier"]
```

Coupled with a Criteria

```
...
    projections {
        max "checkoutDate"
    }
...
```

- Is this the right approach and would not alter the table structure?
- How would I query my data with criteria, expressing the max aggregate for `lastCheckoutDate` and the array I want returned for the `repairHistory`?

Thanks a lot, any help is greatly appreciated.

Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to focus on the main question, which is how to join unrelated entities/domain classes.

## The problem

Unfortunately, as you have discovered, GORM/Hibernate joins require association properties, which results in columns added to the domain class tables. Without the associations the joins cannot be made. This applies to HQL, criteria queries, and where queries. I have an [article](http://emmanuelrosa.com/articles/gorm-for-sqladdicts-from-clause/) on this topic which you may find helpful.

I've never tried using subclassing to solve such a problem, but I don't think it will work one reason being that GORM/Hibernate cannot represent the complex left outer join you're using on the `checkout_journal.checkout_date`.

## Possible solution

You may be able to use database views to simulate the mapping *tables* necessary to create GORM associations. Another developer had [some success](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33166774/how-do-i-get-an-instance-of-a-class-instead-of-its-subclass/33210461#33210461) with this. With proper associations in place you'll be able to use HQL or criteria queries.

*NOTE: Where queries only support inner joins.*

### The RentalCar to CheckoutJournal mapping

Start with the following views (consider them pseudo-SQL):

```
-- This view transforms the checkout_journal table into something GORM compliant by creating a unique key for each journal entry
CREATE VIEW checkout_journal_gorm AS
SELECT CONCAT(identifier, to_char(checkout_date, '-YYYY-MM-DD-HH-MI-SS-US')) as checkout_identifier, renter_name, checkout_date
FROM checkout_journal

-- This view makes it possible to create a one-to-many association from RentalCar to CheckoutJournal.
CREATE VIEW rental_car_checkous AS 
SELECT rc.identifier AS rental_car_identifier, CONCAT(coj.identifier, to_char(coj.checkout_date, '-YYYY-MM-DD-HH-MI-SS-US')) as checkout_identifier
FROM rental_car AS rc INNER JOIN checkout_journal as coj ON rc.indentifier = coj.identifier
```

With the views in place you can use them in the `RentalCar` and `CheckoutJournal` domain classes.

```
class RentalCar {
    String identifier

    static hasMany = [
        checkouts: CheckoutJournal,
        repairs: RepairJournal
    ]

    static mapping = {
        table 'rental_car'
        checkouts joinTable: [
            name: 'rental_car_checkous',
            key: 'rental_car_identifier',
            column: 'checkout_identifier'
        ]
    }
    ...
}

class CheckoutJournal {
    String identifier
    String renterName
    Date checkoutDate

    static mapping = {
        table 'checkout_journal_gorm'
        id column: 'checkout_identifier', name: 'identifier'
    }
    ...
}
```

You can then do the equivalent for the `RepairJournal`.

### GORM queries

With the GORM-compliant domain classes set up (which by-the-way are now read-only), you can use HQL, or criteria queries instead of SQL. Here's an example:

```
RentalCar.withCriteria {
    resultTransformer = new org.hibernate.transform.AliasToEntityMapResultTransformer()
    createAlias 'checkouts', 'c', org.hibernate.sql.JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN
    createAlias 'repairs', 'r', org.hibernate.sql.JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN

    projections {
        groupProperty 'identifier', 'identifier'
        max 'c.checkoutDate', 'lastCheckoutDate'
        groupProperty 'r.repairDate', 'repairDate'
    }
}
```

The output would look like this:

```
[
    [identifier: 'xyz', lastCheckoutDate: '2015-10-31 20:06:17.738831', repairDate: '2015-10-31 20:06:17.738831'],
    [identifier: 'xyz', lastCheckoutDate: '2015-10-31 20:06:17.738831', repairDate: '2015-10-30 20:06:17.738831'],
    [identifier: 'xyz', lastCheckoutDate: '2015-10-31 20:06:17.738831', repairDate: '2015-10-29 20:06:17.738831']
]
```

Such output can be transformed like this:

```
rows.groupBy { it.identifier }.collect { identifier, maps -> 
    [
        identifier: identifier, 
        lastCheckoutDate: maps[0].lastCheckoutDate,
        repairHistory: maps*.repairDate
    ]
}
```

To produce the structure you're looking for:

```
[
    [
        identifier:xyz, 
        lastCheckoutDate:2015-10-31 20:06:17.738831, 
        repairHistory:[
            2015-10-31 20:06:17.738831, 
            2015-10-30 20:06:17.738831, 
            2015-10-29 20:06:17.738831
        ]
    ]
]
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Sounds like a pretty straight forward approach. I like the output transformation. Will try this out soon and update about the outcome.

Comment: My main problem is in configuring joinTable in RentalCar's mapping. Currently I'm held up by the following question: Wouldn't key specify a local field (in table rental_car) and column the foreign field (in checkout_journal_gorm) - see example https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/ref/Database%20Mapping/joinTable.html. Or are both fields in rental_car? The exact meaning of key and inverse column are unclear to me.

Comment: Yes, that is confusing. First, I forgot to set the id of RentalCar: `id generator: 'assigned', name: 'identifier'`. Key means that the id of the RentalCar instance will be in the rental_car_identifier column. Column means that the Id of the CheckoutJournal will be in the checkout_identifier column.

Comment: The issue is currently on hold, the concepts in your answer is definately leading to a solution and got me out of beeing stuck, thats why I marked it as correct. I have some minor diferences in the semantics of the criteria query and will post what worked for me in a month or two, maybe with some additional conclusions.